# Solution of $2^x+3^x=1$

Tags: exponential-function, roots, exponential-sum

Lately, I considered the number $s \in R$ so that $2^s+3^s=1$. Obviously, this number is unique because of the monotonicity of $a^x$ and is approximately $-0.787885$. Also, if $s = -a/b$, then $2^\frac{a}{b}+3^\frac{a}{b}=6^\frac{a}{b}$, which is Fermat's theorem for rational exponents and proven to have no solution, so $s$ is irrational.
My question is: What else is known about $s$? (There don't seem to be many resources about these kinds of numbers.)

Comment: I doubt that much is known about that particular number. Very few numbers that you can write down this way have much lore about them unless they happen to come up in some other part of mathematics.

Comment: There are uncountably many reals, and countably (but infinitely) many satisfying certain equations, so having resources about most of them would explode the web, I guess.